# Looping through PDO result of table

Tags: php, pdo

I have a table named `events` like this with 3 entries:

```
-------------------------------------
| Name | Description | Image | Date |
-------------------------------------
```

I am calling a PDO query such as below:

```
`Connection handled in a class`
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT Name, Description, Image, Date FROM events");
$stmt->execute();

$events = array();
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $events = $row;
    }
}
```

And later in my code when I call upon `$events`:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($events); $x++) {
    echo $events[$x];
}
```

But all that returns for me is:

ArrayArrayArray

Comment: what displays print_r($events[$x]) in loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, look at this statement here in the `while()` loop,

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $events = $row;
           ^ it should be $events[]
}
```

In each iteration you're assigning the array to `$events`, not appending it.

And second, when you do this `echo $events[$x];` it shows *ArrayArrayArray* because `$events[$x]` is actually an array, not a string.

So your code should be like this:

```
// your code

$events = array();
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $events[] = $row;
    }
}

for ($x = 0; $x < count($events); $x++) {
    echo $events[$x]['Name'] . "<br />";

    // like that you can do this
    // echo $events[$x]['Description'];
    // echo $events[$x]['Image'];
    // echo $events[$x]['Date'];
}
```